# Starting array index with 1 instead of 0

Tags: php, arrays

I have a script that outputs results into an `array` via a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($export AS $exp) {
    $_SESSION['export'][] = array($exp->label, $exp->pos_X, $exp->pos_Y);
}
```

It works great however the count starts with 0 and results look odd:

```
0   Value1    34      52
1   Value2   -12      66
2   ValueX    20      47
3   ValueZ   -22      94
```

I'd like it to be

```
1   Value1    34      52
2   Value2   -12      66
3   ValueX    20      47
4   ValueZ   -22      94
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: arrays are zero index. If you want it to start at 1, add +1 to the original index

Comment: _What_ results "look odd"? Are you talking about the value `$SESSION['export']` (why is it important what it "looks like"?) or somewhere that its value is displayed to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to alter value of `key` with `+1` at the time of displaying, then maintain a counter variable `$x` which starts from 1 and keep on incrementing it in loop.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$x=1;
foreach ($export AS $exp) 
{
     $_SESSION['export'][$x] = array($exp->label, $exp->pos_X, $exp->pos_Y);
     $x++;//added this line for incrementing value of $x
}
```

Comment: @santa The next programmer that picks up this code is going to punch someone... Are you going to do this for everyone of your arrays?

Comment: @nerdlyist can i ask you why? in my post i just gave an alternative.

Comment: Mostly for the guy that accepted this. This is overhead, inconsistent and prone to causing error when someone doesn't know what is going on. Your answer is 100% correct just solving something that does not need to be

Comment: @nerdlyist Please look into first line of my post, from my side i tried to explain you can change your key by incrementing one and if you dont want it to be done. then choose my solution.

Comment: I get it an I did not down vote but people looking at this should know it is a bad idea.